# Which orbital will a free electron occupy in a hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

if we were to hold an electron really close to an hydrogen atom that lacks an electron, and then we were to release the electron without adding any kinetic energy to it
Which orbital would that electron occupy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hydrogen atom that lacks an electron is an ion and is called a proton. The energy levels of the hydrogen atom can be seen in the second page [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html) . What you are describing is an electron at the ionization level. It can be caught there and then it will cascade down to the ground level. This will be a quantum mechanical probabilistic problem, i.e. how many photons may be produced by the time the electron is caught in the ground state.It has a high probability of emitting a single 13.6 ev photon falling into the ground state.

Comment: "how many photons may be produced by the time the electron is caught in the ground state." this is interesting, so it can potentially create a photon for each state that it passes ? like, moving through excited states ? but assuming it doesn't have any kinetic energy to begin with, this energy only comes from the acceleration due to the field the electron is exposed to ? (please excuse my newbie terminology)

Comment: yes. classically an electron falling from zero kinetic energy into a potential will radiate continuously  and fall on the proton and become neutralized. This is one of the basic reasons for inventing quantum mechanics, the existence of stable levels on the way down and a ground level which cannot be overcome. Transitions in between have quantized energy for the photons, characteristic of the hydrogen spectrum. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series

Comment: So does this mean there should be 6 photons released ? one for each n level the electron passes ?

Comment: This is quantum mechanics: there will be a probability for six photons to be released in consecutive cascades, and all the other combinati0ns. I have not delved into the problem but I suspect the most probable "combination"will be the ground state of 13.6ev with one photon. I may be wrong

Comment: this is fascinating, is this a thoroughly researched  subject ? where can i read about this ?

Comment: a course of quantum mechanics is necessary to be able to calculate probabilities. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/ .It has been studied for more complex nuclei https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.119.1502  but the mathematics of quantum mechanics are necessary to understand the subject

Answer (score 0):

Orbitals refer to stable atomic or ionic systems. A proton with two electrons would not be stable -- as you say you would have to hold it there with an external force.

Comment: Actually, a proton with two electrons is a negative hydrogen ion. Apparently in free space negative hydrogen ions are (just barely) stable, with [binding energy 0.75 eV](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/kamon/teaching/phys809wcu/Lecture/reference/Negative_Hydrogen_Ion_pp920501.pdf).